# Closed path in the two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, algorithm

There is two-dimensional array of zeros and ones. Need algorithm (the implementation) that determines whether in this array closed path of ones, that surround the zeros

**Example:**

there EXISTS a closed path(center):

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

there is NO

```
0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Looks like homework? There's a tag for that.

Comment: You mean a 0 surrounded by 1s ?

Comment: Oh, so if you had a 2x2 subarray that was all `1`s, that would not be considered a closed path? Looks like one to me.

Comment: Yes, you right, need some zero inside

Comment: Hmm, that makes it somewhat more complex. Without that you could just use graph theory.

Comment: Why Latest zero in second sample is not surrounded?

Comment: because the path from each one to itself is not closed

Answer (score 3):

You can look at *Connected Components Labeling* algorithms, e.g. in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) or google for them. These algorithms are used e.g. to separate foreground pixels from background pixels in a digital white/black image. To apply them to your specific problem, you can think of your matrix as a digital image where 0 means foreground and 1 means background (or vice versa according to your needs). The algorithm finds largest connected foreground regions (containing only 0) that are surrounded by the background (1's). So, if you found such a foreground region you know there is a cycle of 1's surrounding it. When the foreground region is at the boundary you can decide whether you consider it as surrounded or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's homework so I'll just give a general sketch. Construct an undirected graph; each `1` is a node, adjacent `1`s have an edge between them. Google for `undirected graph cycle detection` to find closed paths. Then you have to go back to the original matrix and make sure there's at least one `0` inside.

Comment: What's the definition of adjacent `1`s? Also who said that finding cycle in defined graph causes to find closed path?

Comment: @Saeed Amiri For each `1`, look at the adjacent cells for other `1`s. If there's one there, they're adjacent, add an edge between them. Any closed path, as defined by the OP, will correspond to a cycle in the graph. Unfortunately, due to the constraint that a `0` must be enclosed, the reverse isn't true, so you have to check that.

Comment: First of all what's the meaning of adjacent(in row column or diameter or ...)? Second (by assuming just row and column adjacency), Suppose all squares are `1`s your algorithm returns n^4 Closed Path but there isn't any close path by definition of OP.

Comment: Good point, it's not a good algorithm for that case. The example in the question makes it clear that we should check the diagonals. So for `[x,y]` you look at all the points from `x-1` to `x+1` and `y-1` to `y+1`, except the point itself, and handling the outer boundaries correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to flood-fill starting at each `0` bounded by `1`s. If it doesn't reach an edge, it's surrounded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code i tried. test it through
Logic i tried is loop through all the rows except first and last row.
if you find 0 then check it neighbour to left,right,top and bottom if all the neighbours are 1 then closed.

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[,] graph = new int[5, 5] { 
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 } 
        };

        int[,] graph1 = new int[5, 5] { 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, 
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 } 
        };

        isClosed(graph1);



    }

    private bool isClosed(int[,] graph)
    {


        for (int i = 1; i < graph.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < graph.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                if (graph[i, j] == 0)
                {
                    if (graph[i - 1, j] == 1 && graph[i + 1, j] == 1 && graph[i, j - 1] == 1 && graph[i, j + 1] == 1)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How about more than one zero in surrounded by ones?

Comment: No it doesn't work for all matrices suppose graph like ear lines, It doesn't work for it.